# windows: how to delete all folders containing less than X files

Tags: windows, directory

I have a folder with a lot of subfolders (AI experiments and each parameter change generates a new folder with sometimes only 1 or 2 files). How can I delete all folders containing less than X files?

didn't try anything yet because no idea ;)
Edit: found a solution:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Depth 5 | ForEach-Object {

    $directory = $_.FullName
    $fileCount = (Get-ChildItem $directory | Measure-Object).Count

    if ($fileCount -le 10) {
        Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $directory
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know, but first step: make a removable backup.

Comment: What is your preferred way of doing this? Powershell? Batch script? Something else?

Comment: actually don't care how... batch, PS, tool-software

Comment: @TauTau If you found a solution on your own that's great - but please post it as an answer below, so your question doesn't keep listing as "unanswered" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Depth 5 | ForEach-Object {

$directory = $_.FullName
$fileCount = (Get-ChildItem $directory | Measure-Object).Count

if ($fileCount -le 10) {
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $directory
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**